# How to debug missing default value of managed file?

Tags: forms, files

I have a form with images. It also contains title and alt for 3 languages, so when I select them in one query, I get the same managed file fid 3 times. But that's not the problem.

Relevant part of code is:

```
kpr($image_has_language);
$first_language = reset($image_has_language);
$form['image'][$i] = array (
   '#type' => 'fieldset',
   '#collapsible' => FALSE,
   'ImageFile' => array(
     '#type' => 'managed_file',
     '#default_value' => (integer)$first_language['ImageFile'],
     '#title' => t("Image"),
     '#title_display' => 'invisible',
     // '#description' => t('Allowed extensions: gif png jpg jpeg.'),
     '#upload_validators' => array(
       'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
       'file_validate_size' => array(variable_get('something_image_size', 5 * 1024 * 1024)),
     ),
     '#upload_location' => 'public://something/image',
     '#theme' => 'preview_upload',
   ),
   'id_image' => array(
     '#type' => 'value',
     '#value' => $clone?'new':$first_language['idImage'],
   )
 );
 kpr($form['image'][$i]);
```

Below results of that `kpr`s:

[image: Screenshot - all good]

As you can see, all is perfectly well. File is on disk, file preview work, in database it is marked as permanent and as used.

When I call `var_dump` on `$form_state['values']['image'][0]` in validation function, without changing file on the form, I get:

```
  array(3) {
    ["ImageFile"]=>
    int(0)
    ["id_image"]=>
    string(3) "599"
  }
```

Values in `$_POST` are OK:

```
  ["image"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["ImageFile"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["fid"]=>
        string(4) "3696"
      }
```

**If I change file**, it works as expected:

```
  array(3) {
    ["ImageFile"]=>
    string(4) "3698"
    ["id_image"]=>
    string(3) "599"
  }
```

and in `$_POST`:

```
  ["image"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["ImageFile"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["fid"]=>
        string(4) "3698"
      }
```

How can I identify where my value gets removed? I also have another image on that form, single one (so without `foreach`), and it works OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all can you try to remove the fieldset to a different $form[] array key? Is it really necessary to make it nested like this?

I think if you want to know if the file is added or removed then you can check in the following way.

```
$total_image_count = $form_state['storage']['image_elements']; // The number of image uploaded elements; just as example.
for($i = 0; $i < $total_image_count; $i++) {
  if ($form_state['values']['image'][$i] != 0) {
    // File is not deleted.
  } elseif ($form_state['values']['image'][$i] == 0) {
    //File is deleted.
  }
}
```

However, check with this and let me know.

Comment: Fieldset is needed, because I need to know which alt and title is for which image. And the very problem is that I'm getting `$form_state['values']['image'][$i] == 0` if file is not deleted, but left default. But only on this particular field, so I know there is something wrong, and I just don't know how to debug it, how to find out why between `$_POST` and `$form_state` file ID gets forgotten.

Comment: I still think this is due to the nesting of the fieldset. Can you debug once removing it? Then can be modified to retain the required needs.
Also, I can see your comment in https://www.drupal.org/node/1957602 which is associated with fieldset nesting.

Comment: My comment was about a bit different situation (file not uploaded at all). But good catch. I totally forgot about it. Will try as soon as possible, thanks.

Comment: welcome, if you are able to fix it then please share it so that it may be useful in future. :)

Comment: I hacked around it so far. If I'll manage to debug it, truly, I will post the process and result as an answer. For now? There is nothing I can be proud about.

Comment: See my self-answer, it was reported already

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to debug anything. It seems it was just an effect of [Regression: Files or images attached to certain core and non-core entities are lost when the entity is edited and saved](https://www.drupal.org/node/2305017)

Solution is to downgrade, or wait.