# How to ignore specific Drupal release in update notifications?

Tags: 7, updating

I'm using Drupal 7.28 and getting this message:

> There is a security update available for your version of Drupal. To ensure the security of your server, you should update immediately! See the available updates page for more information and to install your missing updates.

Sadly, [there is a critical bug in 7.29](https://www.drupal.org/node/2305017) that makes this particular release [totally not workable for me](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/124305/16495). No way I'm installing it, it's that simple. I'll either apply some of 7.29 patches manually, or wait for 7.30. Thus, **I don't want to be bothered with release I know I will not install**. How can I make my Drupal ignore it? **I do want to be notified when 7.30 is ready**, so simply turning off all messages about updates is not an answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry Molot.Yes, that's why I deleted my previous comment.

Comment: This: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26079/how-do-i-stop-drupal-checking-for-updates-for-a-specific-module, and remove the system module? Don't let the security team know you're doing this, they won't be happy ;)

Comment: @Clive I've seen it, and I did it for now already. I'm just looking for version-specific way, not project specific. I want to know when 7.30 is out. For security team? I couldn't care less. We are not using private filesystem on that site anyway, so this failed fix helps us with nothing, really. Not where it matters.

Comment: @Mołot You should be able to get quite creative in that hook, I've added a potential answer

Comment: @Clive Thanks. And yes, my bad. I was just tired from ... around the error itself and apparently I stopped thinking for a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: this is definitely **not recommended**. Hiding security updates is bad for all the obvious reasons (it's clear you know that, but for the sake of others who see this...).

As a technical exercise, I can't see why something like this wouldn't work (un-tested):

```
function MYMODULE_update_projects_alter(&$projects) {
  $projects['system']['info']['version'] = '7.29';
}
```

That should basically trick Drupal into thinking core is already at 7.29, so you shouldn't get any warnings. Plus you should also receive update notices for 7.30.